# Changing an Encrypted Attribute to be Deterministic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I have an attribute that was encrypted:

```
encrypts :name
```

I have changed it to be deterministic:

```
encrypts :name, deterministic: true, previous: { deterministic: false }
```

I have old records and with this change I can see the value of the field for both old and new records, however I still cant query for records by name.

```
bobby = Person.create(name: 'bobby')
Person.where(name: 'bobby)
=>Nil
```

How can I make the attribute searchable?

---

Edit:
Testing this feature with a new empty rails installation and it works, so I think it is something to do with the old records. Is that plausible? iI there a workaround?

---

Edit:

A duplicate question about attr_encrypted was suggested.  my question and code isnt usign that gem.  the suggestions do not work for this.

I'm trying to use a core ActiveRecord feature, but am not able to search and asking a question about that.

Comment: no, doesnt seem to be asking the same thing and the things they are suggesting do not work.  im following the guide, but it isnt working, hence the question

Comment: That question is using a gem, i'm asking about a core rails/active record feature: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution? Or did you have to write an algorithm to read the old data and rewrite it to the database again under the new deterministic conditions?

Comment: So, another way I'm thinking of querying the encrypted data is plucking the attributes along with the IDs and then querying the array of results and then looking for the ID based on the result and then accessing the record like that. A huge workaround wasting resources, but that may be another solution?

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly resolve your issue, but it might be a workaround which I have decided to implement because I am using it on a small subset of children and keeps your encryption in your database to the recommended level.

```
array = Person.pluck(:id,:name)
filtered_array = array.select { |item| item.include?("bobby") }
@filtered_people = Person.where(id: filtered_array.map { |x| x[0] })
```

I first create an array with the ID which usually isn't encrypted along with the name which the pluck ensures isn't encrypted.

Then I filter the array on the search query, in your case "bobby".

Lastly, I select the people based on the ID's filtered which is the first array of the set of arrays [0].

How I am using it:

```
@client = Client.find(10)
array = @client.people.pluck(:id,:name)
filtered_array = array.select { |item| item.include?("bobby") }
@filtered_people = @client.people.where(id: filtered_array.map { |x| x[0] }})
```

Comment: yep thats a workaround, if numbre of people is smallish